# How do I add and subtract probability disributions like real numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, probability

I'd like your advice: could you recommend a library that allows you to add/subtract/multiply/divide PDFs (Probability Density Functions) like real numbers?

Behind the scenes, it would have to do a Monte Carlo to work the result out, so I'd probably prefer something fast and efficient, that can take advantage of any GPU in the system.

**Update:**

This is the sort of C# code I am looking for:

```
  var a = new Normal(0.0, 1.0); // Creates a PDF with mean=0, std. dev=1.0.
  var b = new Normal(0.0, 2.0); // Creates a PDF with mean=0, std. dev=2.0.
  var x = a + b; // Creates a PDF which is the sum of a and b.
                 // i.e. perform a Monte Carlo by taking thousands of samples 
                 // of a and b to construct the resultant PDF.
```

**Update:**

What I'm looking for is a method to implement the algebra on "probability shapes" in [The Flaw of Averages](http://www.flawofaverages.com/) by Sam Savage. The video [Monte Carlo Simulation in Matlab](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZkdDHHkVQ8) explains the effect I want - a library to perform math on a series of input distributions.

**Update:**

Searching for the following will produce info on the appropriate libraries:

- "monte carlo library"
- "monte carlo C++"
- "monte carlo Matlab"
- "monte carlo .NET"

Comment: Do you mean: if X and Y are random variables with PDFs P and Q, you want the PDFs for X+Y, X-Y, X*Y and X/Y? (That's not what you say, but I guess it's what you mean.) And what representation of PDF are you talking about? Are they represented as code? As tables? Some other descriptor?

Comment: Yes, this is the effect I want, but more generic, i.e some library that parses any function you specify to produce an output probability density function. The PDFs start life as distributions bootstrapped from existing sampled data, or generated manually given some paramaters (i.e normal distribution with a standard deviation of 1.5).

Comment: Before you ask this question you need to be able to specify it precisely. At the moment you don't appear to have a concrete spec.

Comment: I've updated the question, as per your comment, to give an example.

Comment: you might consider tagging this with "functional programming" "scientific computing" "f#" ... you would probably get some more helpful answers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [@Risk Developer](http://www.palisade.com/devkits/rdk.asp) Kit allows you to start with a set of probability density functions, then perform algebra on the inputs to get some output, i.e. P = A + B.

The keywords [on this page](http://www.palisade.com/devkits/rdk.asp) can be used to find other competing offerings, e.g. try searching for:

- "monte carlo simulation model C++"
- "monte carlo simulation model .NET"
- "risk analysis toolkit"
- "distributing fitting capabilties".

Its not all that difficult to code this up in a language such as C++ or .NET. The Monte Carlo portion is probably only about 50 lines of code:

- Read "[The Flaw Of Averages](http://www.flawofaverages.com/)" by Sam Savage to understand how you can use algebra on "probability shapes".
- Have some method of generating a "probability shape", either by bootstrapping from some sampled data, or from a pre-determined probability density function, or by using the [Math.NET probability library](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/probability-distributions/).
- Take 10000 samples from the input probability shapes.
- Do the algebra on the samples, i.e. +, -, /, *, etc, to get 1000 outputs. You can also form a probability tree which implies and, or, etc on the inputs.
- Combine these 10000 outputs into a new "probability shape" by putting the results into 100 discrete "buckets".
- Now that we have a new "probability shape", we can then use that as the input into a new probability tree, or perform an integration to get the area, which converts it back into a hard probability number given some threshold.
- The video [Monte Carlo Simulation in Matlab](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZkdDHHkVQ8) explains this entire process much better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

@Gravitas - Based on that exchange with @user207442, it sounds like you just want an object that abstracts away a convolution for addition and subtraction.  There is certainly a closed form solution for the product of two random variables, but it might depend on the distribution.

C#'s hot new step sister, F#, let's you do some fun FP techniques, and it integrates seamlessly with C#.  Your goal of abstracting out a "random variable" type that can be "summed" (convolved) or "multiplied" (??) seems like it is screaming for [a monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29).  Here is a [simple example](http://blog.matthewdoig.com/?p=98).

Edit: do you need to reinvent mcmc in c#? we use winbugs for this at my school ... this is the c++ library winbugs uses: http://darwin.eeb.uconn.edu/mcmc++/mcmc++.html.  rather than reinventing the wheel, could you just wrap your code around the c++ (again, seems like monads would come in hand here)?

Comment: But how would the actual implementation look like?

Comment: What I do want is something that abstracts away convolution for not only addition or subtraction, but for any arbitrary formula that has some random variable as an input. If we are dealing with non-standard distributions, or non-standard algebra (what is the probability distribution of a random variable when you square it?) then Monte Carlo is a generic solution that just works (albeit at the cost of more CPU than a non-Monte Carlo solution).

Comment: @svick I will try to make a monad(ish?) example in F#, if that would be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Math.NET Numerics library. [Here](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/probability-distributions/) is the page specific to probability distribution support.

Comment: This library allows you to create Probability Density Functions. However, what I'm looking for is the ability to add and subtract these probability density functions, something which Math.NET does not support.